# Is there any example such that $\lim\limits_{k \to \infty} S_{2k} < \infty$ but $\lim\limits_{k \to \infty} S_k = \infty$?

Tags: convergence-divergence

Let $S_k = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{k}a_n$ be a series.
Is there any example that
$\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty}S_{2k}$ exists but $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is convergent.

Comment: This question makes no sense.  Is there a missing "not" before the last word?

Comment: Take $a_n:=(-1)^n$.

Comment: It would also help, once you edit your query, to please make sure that your query's title is kept consistent with your query.

Comment: $0,1,0,2,0,3,...$

Comment: @Dole What are your $a_n$'s?

Comment: @Gary Difference of that series so that $a_n:=0,1,-1,2,-2,3,...$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Counter-example is easy to construct.

We try to choose $(a_{n})$ such that $S_{n}=\begin{cases}
n, & \mbox{if }n\mbox{ is odd}\\
0, & \mbox{if }n\mbox{ is even}
\end{cases}.$ This is possible by solving equations. For example, $a_{1}=S_{1}=1$,
$a_{2}=S_{2}-S_{1}=-1$, $a_{3}=S_{3}-S_{2}=3$, etc...

Clearly $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}S_{2n}=0$ while $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}S_{n}$
does not exist.

Comment: Note that it is impossible that $\lim_n S_n = \infty$ because $(S_n)$ has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: we say lim S_n DNE because it alternates right?